# C# WPF is running animation very choppily. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

This is my code. It is critical that the rotation be run as smoothly as possible but when I run it it is extremely choppy and I really don't know why!

```
<Window.Resources >
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisConverter" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="RenderingImage"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
            From="0" To="{Binding To}" Duration="{Binding Duration}"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever" SpeedRatio="0.25" FillBehavior="Stop" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:AnimationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{Binding EscapeSession}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding RunSession}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<i:Interaction.Triggers >
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AnimationLoaded}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid Background="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform >
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.7" ScaleY="1.7" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeSpan}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Image Source="{Binding MemoryMappedImage}" x:Name="RenderingImage"
           Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisConverter}}"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform >
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="0" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How often is `{Binding TimeSpan}` being updated?

Comment: That's for a countdown element but it is not running wehen the animation is rotating the image.

Comment: And when it does run its to the order of seconds.

Comment: Is your animation running slow? When the duration is long and/or the speedratio is very low it may look very sloppy.

Comment: It's weird it starts lagging, relaizes it needs to catch up, speeds up rinse wash repeat. Can I change the dispatcher priority to high on thew doubleanimation?